# Why is pip saying it is an invalid argument?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to host a bot on discord using heroku. For this, I need to make a requirements file, but to get the information I need for it, I need to use `pip freeze`. When I try to run this command, I get this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\opboi\onedrive\desktop\fundamentals\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "c:\users\opboi\onedrive\desktop\fundamentals\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\opboi\OneDrive\Desktop\Fundamentals\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\opboi\onedrive\desktop\fundamentals\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\main.py", line 45, in main
  File "c:\users\opboi\onedrive\desktop\fundamentals\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
  File "c:\users\opboi\onedrive\desktop\fundamentals\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I am unsure as to why this happens, but any help would be appreciated. I have also tried `py -3 -m pip freeze to` to see if that would change anything, but nothing did. Nothing other than `pip install` and `pip uninstall` work either. I installed pip along with my python 3.7 if that makes any difference

Comment: `pip list` is working?

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: No commands other than pip install and pip uninstall work

Comment: Anything here helps? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError+Errno+22+Invalid+argument

Comment: I just rebooted my computer and it worked